# I cant fetch the data using ajax i dont know why

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

is any one can help how to fix this one... I already inserted , but if i select nothing happens..

[image]

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: please include all relevant code in OP not just a picture.. check [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where do you trigger the function display?

Comment: if i console it there is no error happens..

Comment: Are you looking for a photoshoped answer? I guess no... So post relevant code in question itself!

Comment: at the displaymessage.php

Comment: Parse the data in jquery. Use data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: I want to help but the screenshot is annoying. Include your code in the question, not a screen shot.

Comment: You need to call the function from somewhere, it wont call itself automatically. Also, I suggest you use `GET` for requests which don't modify the server state and only get data.

Answer (score 0):

You must call display function after page load!
In script

```
(function($) {
    function disply(){
        /*YOUR DISPLAY CODE*/
    };
    $(function() {
        disply();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: No, you don't must but should. Usually, ajax request takes longer to complete than DOM to be ready especially if not cached